# SQL OUTER JOIN -- How to refer to the tables in explanations?

Tags: sql, outer-join

If you want to explain outer joins, you can say: In a left outer join .... the *left table*... the *right table* ....  Or, alternatively: in a right outer join ... the *right table* .... the *left table*.... Obviously, *left table* and *right table* change roles.

Is there an abstract name/concept referring at the same time to left table in a left join and the right table in a right join? Another one, referring to the right table in the left join and also to  the left table in the right join?

Some ideas: "Base table", "Fixed table", "Open table", "Loose table"?

Comment: I don't know of any common names. The good thing is: almost nobody uses right outer joins because they can be very hard to read. We only use left outer joins or full outer joins. Thus we don't really have to care about the correct wording in left outer joins versus right outer joins :-) We really just say left-hand table and right-hand table usually. Sometimes I use the expression outer-joined table, too.

Comment: "the inner table" & "the outer table" are used with certain meanings in some DBMS manuals. But if you are going to use such terminology you'd better define it.